# Fetch the MAX(date) from table1 which is < MIN(date) from table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I have a Table1(Master table(AAA)) and Table2(sub_master table(BBB)).
I already fetch some data from AAA to BBB by using some condition.

(Table1 AAA)

```
ID          Date1                   Grade1
1           2013-07-12 00:00:00.000 1 
1           2014-04-02 00:00:00.000 1 
1           2014-12-29 00:00:00.000 NULL
100000      2012-10-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
100000      2015-10-08 00:00:00.000 NULL
100000      2017-01-10 00:00:00.000 1 
100000      2018-05-29 00:00:00.000 2
```

Table 2 BBB

```
ID          Date2                   Grade2
1           2013-07-12 00:00:00.000 1 
1           2014-04-02 00:00:00.000 1 
100000      2017-01-10 00:00:00.000 1 
100000      2018-05-29 00:00:00.000 2
```

Now i want to fetch the another few data from AAA to BBB using the another condtion.

choose the MIN(date2) and find the MAX(date1) < MIN(date2) and WHERE Grade1 IS NULL

Which means the OP should be like

```
100000      2015-10-08 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

Please help me solve this problem 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: the `OP` is from which table ?

Comment: @Squirrel From AAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
           -- Get Max of Date1 with Grade1 is null vallue
           SELECT ID, Date1 = MAX(Date1)
           FROM   Table1
           WHERE  Grade1 IS NULL
           GROUP BY ID
       ) t1
       INNER JOIN
       (
           -- Get Min of Date2
           SELECT ID, Date2 = MIN(Date2)
           FROM   Table2
           GROUP BY ID
       ) t2
       ON  t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE  t1.Date1 < t2.Date2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below

```
 with 
  t1 as    
 (
   select id,max(date1) as date1 from AAA where grade1 is null
   group by id
  ), 
  t2 as

  (
  select id, min(date2) as  date2 from BBB group by id
  ) select t1.*,t2.*
     from t1 join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
     where t1.date1<t2.date2
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Max(Date1) from AAA where Date1 <
(Select MIN(DATE2) from BBB)
AND GRADE1 is NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by translating your English directly into sql:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM aaa
WHERE date1 < (SELECT MIN(date2)FROM bbb) and grade1 is null
ORDER BY date1 desc
```

The nuts and bolts are from your English requirement: they get all rows with a date less than the min from table 2. The row having the max date is the top 1 row ordered by date descending

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT ID, MAX(Date1)
           FROM   Table1
           WHERE  Grade1 IS NULL
           GROUP BY ID
       ) t1
       INNER JOIN
       (
           SELECT ID, Date2 = MIN(Date2)
           FROM   Table2
           GROUP BY ID
       ) t2
       ON  t1.ID = t2.ID
and t1.Date1 < t2.Date2
```